# Vuejs : how to mix static and dynamic content in template?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Here is my vueJS template

```js
template: `
  <div>
    <div>{{ date}}</div>
    <div>{{ titre }}</div>
    <div>username: <a href='#fiche?username={{ username }}'>{{ username }}</a></div>
  </div>`
```

Problem comes when I try to mix some static string `#fiche` with `{{ username }}`

Some alternative would be to use:

```html
<div>username: <a :href='link'>{{ username }}</a></div>
```

and define link or define a getFiche function I guess.

```js
methods:{
  getFiche: function(username) {
    return "#fiche?" + username;
  }
},
```

Is there are any "quicker" method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use javascript in attribute binding:

```js
<a :href="`#fiche?username=${username}`">
```

Or `<a :href="'#fiche?username=' + username">`

Notice, both

```js
`#fiche?username=${username}`
```

and

```js
'#fiche?username=' + username
```

are simply javascript expressions that dynamically create the url.

Answer (score 0):

> and define link or define a getFiche function I guess.

Methods are evaluated on ever *tick* whereas a computed property only runs when required so they are preferred for this sort of thing.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods

```js
template: `...
  <a :href="ficheLink">{{username}}</a>
  ...`,
computed: {
  ficheLink () {
    return `#fiche?username=${this.username}`
  }
}
```